# Python splitting strings and jumbling the middle

Tags: python, string, split

I am having trouble with a program in python...I need the program to jumble the middle of words while keeping the outer two letters intact...I believe I have successfully split the word into three different sections, I just can't figure out how I am supposed to scramble the middle of the word

```
word = input("Enter a word")

first_letter = word[0]

last_letter = word[-1]

still_to_scramble = word[1:-1]
```

Should I use randoms? Or is there a simple way, sorry I am relatively new to coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `shuffle` from the random package:

```
import random
letters = list(still_to_scramble)
random.shuffle(letters)
scrambled = ''.join(letters)
```

Here's how it would work:

```
>>> s
'$123abc$'
>>> first_letter = s[0]
>>> last_letter = s[-1]
>>> middle_parts = list(s[1:-1])
>>> random.shuffle(middle_parts)
>>> ''.join(middle_parts)
'b3a2c1'
```

Be careful and don't do this:

```
>>> middle_parts_random = random.shuffle(middle_parts)
```

`shuffle` works *in place* - that's a fancy way of saying it does't return the shuffled bit, but modifies it instead. It actually returns `None`, and you may get tripped up by it, since you won't see an error:

```
>>> middle_parts_random = random.shuffle(middle_parts)
>>> middle_parts_random # Huh? nothing is printed!
>>> middle_parts_random == None # Ah, that's why. Darn you in-place methods!
True
```

Comment: random.shuffle works in place -- in other words, it won't work on strings.  You need something like ` scramble = list(word[1:-1]); shuffle(scramble); print '{0}{1}{2}'.format(first,''.join(scramble),last)`

Comment: One-liner: `'{0}{1}{2}'.format(s[0], ''.join(random.sample(s[1:-1], len(s)-2)), s[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

I've added a regular expression to extend Burhan Khalid's solution above.  This addition works for input with multiple words which I think some might find useful.

```
$ cat ./jumble.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import random

def jumble(s):
    l = list(s)
    random.shuffle(l)
    return(''.join(l))

line = raw_input("Input string to jumble: ")
print(re.sub(r'\b(\w)(\w+)(\w)\b', lambda m: "".join([m.group(1),jumble(m.group(2)),m.group(3)]), line))
```

For example:
    $ ./jumble.py
    Input string to jumble: I am just entering some arbitrary string
    I am jsut etnrneig some aabtrrriy sritng

*Note: The above example was done on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 system with the default python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64*