# Python, defining a function and accessing it

Tags: python, list, function, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python splitting strings and jumbling the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033724/python-splitting-strings-and-jumbling-the-middle)

I have a program in python that I am really stuck on, my purpose of this is to take a sentence from a user and jumble the middle of the word leaving the outer to letters intact...My teacher says I need to do something with parameters but I really have no clue how too access or use my function at all...

```
import random


user_words = input("Enter a word or sentence: ") #Gets user input

word = list(user_words.split()) #Creating a word list of the user input


def Jumble_One_Word(x):

    if len(user_words) > 2: #Only need to change words longer than 2

      first_letter = user_words[0] #Takes the first letter out and defines it

      last_letter = user_words[-1] #Takes the last letter out and defines it

      letters = list(user_words[1:-1]) #Takes the rest and puts them into a list

      random.shuffle(letters) #shuffles the list above

      middle_letters = "".join(letters) #Joins the shuffled list

      final_word = "".join([first_letter, middle_letters, last_letter]) #Puts final      word all back  in place as a list

    print(final_word)#Prints out the final word all back together again


Jumbler_Count = -1

for i in range(len(word)):
    Jumbler_Count + 1
    Word1 = Jumble_One_Word(word[Jumbler_Count])
```

SAMPLE INPUT: HELLO MY NAME IS
EXPECTED OUTPUT: HLELO MY NMAE IS
RESULTED OUTPUT: H leai El moymns
Hoi ynmeEa lm ls
Hiyn  l oelEamms
H naellmEyo m is

Comment: No, It is the same program but I'm having different errors/obstacles.

Comment: `list(user_words.split())` is redundant, just use `user_words.split()`.

Comment: Post the full traceback if you get an error. Else, post a sample input and the expected output

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: there isn't necessarily a traceback, it seems like there only a very cruel teacher that doesn't explain anything at all.

Comment: @Gil str.split() should split the string into a list of words, which appears to be what the poster wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to work on `x` inside the function, and you were working on `user_words` instead.

```
import random

user_words = input("Enter a word or sentence: ") #Gets user input

word = user_words.split()  #no need of list()

def Jumble_One_Word(x):

    if len(x) > 2: #Only need to change words longer than 2


      first_letter = x[0] #Takes the first letter out and defines it

      last_letter = x[-1] #Takes the last letter out and defines it

      letters = list(x[1:-1]) #Takes the rest and puts them into a list

      random.shuffle(letters) #shuffles the list above

      middle_letters = "".join(letters) #Joins the shuffled list

      final_word = "".join([first_letter, middle_letters, last_letter]) #Puts finalword all back  in place as a list

      return final_word # better return from function inste


for i in word:                 #you can iterate this way too
    print (Jumble_One_Word(i))
```

**output:**

```
$ python3 abc.py
Enter a word or sentence: python guido spam
pyhton
giudo
sapm
```

Comment: I like your way a lot...but I get HEllo
None
name
None       When I enter : hello my name is

Comment: Nvm I just had to reverse the lex(x) > 2: and make it return the word...then it works. THANKS

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing some things up and over-complicate others.

First of all, you should but your code in a `main()` function, to make clear where it starts.

Also, in this piece of code:

```
Jumbler_Count = -1

for i in range(len(word)):
    Jumbler_Count + 1
    print Jumble_One_Word(word[Jumbler_Count])
```

`Jumbler_Count` is unnecessary here, just iterate over the word list itself.

So let's create a `main()` function:

```
def main():
    user_words = raw_input("Enter a word or sentence: ") #Gets user input
    words = user_words.split() #Creating a word list of the user input    

    for word in words:
        print Jumble_One_Word(word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here's a slightly altered version of your `Jumble_One_Word` function:

```
def Jumble_One_Word(word):
    if len(word) <= 2: #Only need to change words longer than 2
        return word

    first_letter = word[0] #Takes the first letter out and defines it
    last_letter = word[-1] #Takes the last letter out and defines it
    letters = list(word[1:-1]) #Takes the rest and puts them into a list
    random.shuffle(letters) #shuffles the list above
    middle_letters = "".join(letters) #Joins the shuffled list
    return "".join([first_letter, middle_letters, last_letter]) #Puts final      word all back
```

Note that in your version, you actually never use the parameter `x`. I renamed it to `word` to make it clearer what it is, and also use it instead of `user_words`, which is totally wrong here.

I also removed the print statement and have the function return the jumbled word, since it is good practice to seperate data processing and IO.

Comment: Just spent like 2 minutes writing a code like yours, then return to see a bunch of answers :(

Answer (score 0):

The side of `Word1 = Jumble_One_Word(word[Jumbler_Count])` to the right of the `=` sign (the assignment operator) is the function call.  You're passing `word[Jumbler_Count]` to your function as an argument.

However, inside your function, you're naming that argument `x`... and then not using it!  The "one word" in "jumble one word" is the argument, `x`.  But you're trying to access the word list directly from inside the function.

Instead of manipulating `user_words` from inside your function, you need to manipulate `x`.

Additionally, inside your loop you're assigning the results of every iteration of your function to the same variable.  Every time you go through the loop, you'll overwrite your previous answer, so once your function does work, you'll only ever see the last answer.  Try either making a `results` list with `results = []` before the loop and then using `results.append(Jumble_One_Word(your_argument))` or else just replacing the entire function call line with a `print` statement of the result so the result is displayed immediately.

By the way, your loop can be greatly simplified (this is an example that uses the print statement strategy but you can also do `results.append()` if you create that list):

```
for item in word:
    print Jumble_One_Word(item)
```